# Map editor for indoor navigation

Tags: ios, google-maps, mapbox, indoor-positioning-system, map-edit

I would like to create indoor navigation app. But have some trouble with a floor plan.
And I need a good map(floor) editor maybe like ArcGis,JOSM.
Will be great if this editor can create database by map (door, windows, corridors,...).
I will integrate this map in iOS app.
Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found solution. I had this floor plan in jpg. [image: map]

My steps:
1)Convert your image through GDAL to Gtiff.
2)Create project in TileMill without globe.
3)Press on the button "Add new layer".
4)Choose destination to your gtiff file and type in SRS field "900913".
5)Save.
6)In the CSS set on the image layer raster-scaling:bilinear;
7)Zoom your map while you will see the map.
8)Export your project to MBTile.
9)Use MapBox SDK to integrate your MBTile.
[image: integrated map]
For GDAL:
gdal_translate \
-of GTiff \
~/Downloads/Plateosaurus_big.jpg \
~/Downloads/Plateosaurus_big.tif

Comment: Hello @iraklii .. I also want to do the same. But difficult to understand 7th and 9th step.

Comment: Dear @ajeet.cody:
Step 9, that show map.mbtile file on iOS devices I have used MapBox SDK.
Step 7, when you add layer and config it, sometimes you cannot see the image, so you should zoom the map that see your image.

Comment: Thanks @Iirakii. I will try to do it. But tell me one thing as my I am getting it that, Will it also provide a proper navigation in office floor ? I mean, I want to a office indoor navigation with accuracy of user position. I hope it make sense for u ?

Comment: @ajeetsharma for navigation I have used iBeacons. iBeacons can resolve problem with floor, but for good accuracy needed more iBeacons.

Comment: how did you add this red path

Comment: @Iraklii Is it possible to AR indoor navigation without iBeacons. If yes can you please update me..

Comment: @PvDev hello, you should use everything what can help you detect location, also maybe this link will help you with maps. https://register.apple.com/resources/imdf/

Answer (score 2):

You are free to choose **any vector GIS** you like to use to create indoor floor plans. Thus, you need to **develop an speficiation** for your model, so that you can create rules for routers etc. Next you need to think about how to store them (shapefiles, PostGIS, ...) and how you want to create the final products (rendered maps, routing graphs, ...).

I'm not sure how you want to create/collect your floorplans (experts vs. VGI) but **JOSM** sounds like a good starting point, esp. as the OSM community has already some experience with indoor mapping: http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Indoor

*Hint 1: There seems to be currently no final solution to indoor geolocation with adequat resoluton for your usecase (indoor routing).

Hint 2: The indoor topic is only in use within a very small part of the OSM community. So expect some refuses/critics if you add such data to the global OSM database.

Hint 3: In some countries are floorplans also intellectual property, so copy&trace might be a copyright infridgement.*

Answer (score 2):

Although that's not what it was made for, you could check out [indoo.rs](http://indoo.rs). You can use the product without indoor localization, but indoor map creation and indoor navigation.